# How to display text next to ascii art (in terminal) in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, ascii

I would like to display some ascii art in this format:

```
 _,-,  Name: Powerful Axe
T_  |  Rarity: Yellow Rarity (77.5)
||`-'  Attack: 100
||     Defense: 100
||     Speed: 100
~~     Gold Value: 10

an axe that is really rare
```

I want it in a column layout, kind of like neofetch does, but in NodeJS.
I get all this data from a json file, and I am using the following function to format and color the key pair type values:

```
const chalk = require('chalk')

function keyValue(key, value) {
    return chalk.green(key) + ": " + chalk.yellow(value)
}
```

This all needs to be in the terminal, and preferably not using node-curses or blessed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very inefficient and bloated solution:

```
function print2MultiLine(string, string2) {
    var arr1 = string.split("\n");
    var arr2 = string2.split("\n");
    if (arr1.length > arr2.length) {
        while (arr1.length > arr2.length) {
            arr2.push("");
        }
    } else if (arr1.length < arr2.length) {
        while (arr1.length < arr2.length) {
            arr1.push("");
        }
    }
    var longestLine = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i].length > longestLine) {
            longestLine = arr1[i].length;
        }
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        while (arr1[i].length < longestLine) {
            arr1[i] += " ";
        }
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        console.log(arr1[i] + "  " + arr2[i]);
    }
}
```

if you like comments:

```
function print2MultiLine(string, string2) {
    

    // for each line in each string, print it out 3 spaces away from the other
    var arr1 = string.split("\n");
    var arr2 = string2.split("\n");

    // if one string is longer than the other, make the shorter one the length of the longer one
    
    if (arr1.length > arr2.length) {
        while (arr1.length > arr2.length) {
            arr2.push("");
        }
    } else if (arr1.length < arr2.length) {
        while (arr1.length < arr2.length) {
            arr1.push("");
        }
    }

    // get the length of the longest line in arr1
    var longestLine = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i].length > longestLine) {
            longestLine = arr1[i].length;
            
        }
    }


    // make all other lines in arr1 the length of the longest line
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        while (arr1[i].length < longestLine) {
            arr1[i] += " ";
        }
    }

    // print out the strings
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        console.log(arr1[i] + "  " + arr2[i]);
    }
}
```

Preview:

[image: preview]